# To pass JSF(primefaces) managed bean variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF/primefaces managed bean.I am trying to pass managed bean variable  to JavaScript function within the same managed bean but i am not successful. Can someone please help me in achieving this task.

My managed bean code snippet

```
reportName=report[0];
    url="http://cvgapp42q/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fLPSR%2f"+reportName;
    try {

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('#{repBean.url}')");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**url** is the variable which i am trying to refer using the expression #{repBean.url} in the javascript function **window.open()**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

just put your javascript code in a panel on your page:

```
<h:panelGroup id="scriptPanel">
    <script>
        window.open('#{repBean.url}');
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and update this panel after your ajax request, using `update="scriptPanel"` on your related primefaces component.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{repBean}")
RepBean repBean
```

and in your method

```
try {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('"+repBean.getUrl()+"')");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for the reply.repBean.getUrl() gets the url of the current page.But i am opening a new url http://cvgapp42q/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx..... as mentioned in the question.I just wanted to know how to pass variable **url** that holds url value to the js function so that the value is detectable and new web page is opened.

Comment: I don't know if I really understand what you want (it is probably because of my bad english). If you just want to open the `url` you can use `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('"+url+"')");